# In-App Billing Test Through USB Connected Device

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am new to Android Dev - but I was under the impression that to test in-app billing purchases you must publish the app to a test track through the Play Console, download to a licensed device, and then purchases will show the Test Credit Card options?

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

However, with a phone I have connected via usb debugging to Android Studio, I am able to build and run the app directly to the phone. When I attempt an in-app consumable purchase, I get the prompt to use the Test Credit Credit (initializing a billing test without being changed). I am logged into this device under my google account, which is the developer account.

My question is: I thought an in-app billing test is only initiated when you publish and distribute to the play console test track, with test users added and opted-in? I am logged into the same developer google account on the phone, but I am not added as a tester and I am not testing/publishing through a play console test track. I am just running it through Android Studio with a phone plugged into usb.

Has something changed where if the developer account is signed into the phone connected to android studio via usb it will automatically initiate a test credit card instead of having to go through the publishing to a test track when you initiate a Run to the connected phone?

Comment: i don't think your question has anything to do with android studio, so i've removed the reference to it completely, but the rest seems fine